# Rundeck StreamingLogWriter - Stream Options and Results

Tags: rundeck

How to send *options* (variables) and *steps results* from a Job to Logstash using StreamingLogWriter?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using NotificationPlugin.